# MoPub Unity NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, noclassdeffounderror, mopub

I have been trying to implement the MoPub plugin to a Android Unity Project and I followed the instructions from here:

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-unity-android-plugin

But for some reason the app crashed because of the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubConversionTracker$1

The class mentioned is in the Eclipse project.

I did rename a main folder inside src to main_ to avoid the "Cannot nest 'mopub-sdk/src/main/java' inside mopub-sdk/src". To enable the nesting exclude ',ain/' from 'mopub-sdk/src'" error at Eclipse.

Could someone kindly tell me what's wrong?

I hope it is not a stupid question, I am not very familiar with Eclipse...

Thanks :) !

P.S. My Original Question is posted in Unity Answer, which have images that may illustrate the error and Eclipse project hierarchy better:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/919073/mopub-unity-noclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: you have introduced this error by adding the _ with main.